# Restore with backup & migrate module does not work with Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: backups

Having messed up my dev site (running on Win 7 using Acquia Dev Desktop), I restored a backup I took a few hours ago with the Backup & Migrate module. Now when I click the local site name in Acquia Dev Desktop I get a Choose Language message from Drupal instead of my site. I'm certain I had this problem a few months ago, but I apparently did not make good notes because I don't know where I found the instructions to fix this problem. My guess is that the $database parameters are wrong in settings.php or maybe there's some other problem.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reasons for this not working for you but as long as you've got the database backup and a copy of your existing codebase, you should be fine. Fixing DevDesktop database issues is a little tricky but the easiest way is to just create a new instance with the correct settings. Quick steps to do this:

- We're going to be deleting the whole site instance using DevDesktop so you should make a backup of the folder and your database backup or at least move it outside of the DevDesktop folder.
- Now from the DevDesktop application, delete your site and then create another one with the same name, etc. This will create a new database and a new settings.php file that is connected to it.
- Finally, you'll want to copy your codebase back into this directory
  (making sure not to overwrite the settings.php or sites.php files
  that DevDesktop created) and then try the restore again using backup
  & migrate.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm running again! I will create a new question about sites.php & settings.php.