# What is the purpose of sites.php and how does it relate to settings.php?

Tags: configuration

What is the purpose of sites.php and how does it relate to settings.php?

I have done a lot of web searches and looked at the comments in these files, but cannot find a simple explanation.

Comment: Did you read the text inside example.sites.php?

Comment: And the keyword to look for in google is "Drupal multisite" or "multi-site".

Comment: Most of the time the sites.php is not needed.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7

Comment: I'm confused after reading the api link. It's as if sites.php is used only on Sundays when it rains otherwise it's used along with settings.php on Mondays only. It all seems like gibberish. The thing that prompted this question was when I somehow totally messed up my dev site. The solution (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169294/restore-with-backup-migrate-module-does-not-work-with-acquia-dev-desktop/169295#169295) referred to settings.php and sites.php. What I'm getting so far is that these two files have to do with multi-sites only?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`conf_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path/7) should help clarify the relationship here. `conf_path()` builds the default subdirectory (inside the **sites** directory) Drupal will goto for **settings.php** (and other site-specific configurations). It's default search behavior can be overridden with **sites.php**.